# How to design iOS in landscape mode for all devices in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, xcode6

I want to design the iOS devices screen for landscape only. I have tried going to **Attribute inspector->Orientation->Landscape**  but screen is always visible in portrait mode. From bottom I have tried changing the size classes but I don't get any option for designing in landscape mode only for all devices. How to do this?

Comment: `Attribute inspector->Orientation->Landscape` is only for preview purpose.

Answer (score 1):

First this you need to set Orientation in project setting

[image]

change here After this Change in Attribute inspector->Orientation->Landscape

[image]

After doing these setups you will see your xib showing in landscape mode

[image]

And Also change Simulator Orientation Using key Command(Windows)+ArrowKey . Try this ..

Comment: I am using xcode 6.I have tried all your options.I am also using storyboard so i am using concept of size classes.

Comment: Yes..See i am using Xcode 6 which uses concept of size classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit it in your my**app.plist file like this:

---

1. ```html
   <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
     <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
     <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
   ```

   ## #